# pytest-django how test excel response

Tags: django, pytest

I have a `HttpResponse` with excel file, but I don't know how to test it.

```
def request():
    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    ws = wb.add_sheet('test')

    # write data to sheet, balabala...
    # ws.write(0, 0, 'hello')

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="test.xls"'
    wb.save(response)
    return response
```

When I use pytest-django to test this this function, I dont know how to get excel which is in the response and how test it.

thanks very much
:)

Comment: thanks very much. this is what I want.